# Creating an ActiveRecord with a foreign key outside default_scope throws a Validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, relational-database, default-scope

Creating a product with `warehouse_x (foreign key to Warehouse table)` that is outside default_scope i.e. warehouse_x has `warehouse_type **damage**`.

Unable to create record and throwing error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Warehouse must exist
```

Schema

```
create_table "product", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "unit_price"
    t.bigint "warehouse_id", null: false

    ...

    t.index ["warehouse_id"], name: "index_stock_details_on_warehouse_id"
  end

create_table "warehouses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "warehouse_name"

    ...

    t.integer "warehouse_type", default: 0
  end
```

Warehouse model (warehouse.rb)

```
class Warehouse < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products

  default_scope {where(warehouse_type: :ok_product)}

  scope :damaged, -> {unscoped.where(warehouse_type: :damage)}

  enum warehouse_type: {
    ok_product: 0,
    damage_product: 2
  }

end
```

Product model (product.rb)

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :warehouse
end
```

How can I create a record with foreign key outside default (relation table).

Answer (score 1):

Is validation generated by your belongs_to association, you can disable like this:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :warehouse, optional: true
end
```

Comment: I need to keep warehouse, it can't be optional

Comment: You can set the association as optional, and then validate that warehouse_id is present. In this way you can add products that belongs to warehouses that are not in warehouses table.

Comment: No, my case is different.